# How to close a window but still have app current active?

Tags: c#, wpf

suppose i have 2 windows: InputWindow and DisplayWindow

Currently:i want to use InputWindow to hold data via an App variable

```
// in InputWindow
(App.Current as App).u_id = obj.id;
```

where u_id is the object i defined in app.xaml.cs and obj.id is the input variable in InputWindow.

However when i close InputWindow and display DisplayWindow:

```
// in InputWindow
DisplayWindow window = new DisplayWindow();
window.Show();
Application.Current.MainWindow.Close();
```

The app also kill the data in the InputWindow.

So my question is:

Is there a way to keep the data via from the closed Window to the open Window?

Comment: maybe im still  not clear about this, if i dont close the InputWindow via the above command, the data in the app is still there, but if close it, then that data i referenced is null in DisplayWindow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
        Application.Current.MainWindow.Hide();
```

You can hide the window using this line... or you can pass the information that you want to use into the new window using the constructor.

```
        DisplayWindow window = new DisplayWindow(object myObject);
```

That constructor must have the information you want passed but this can solve the issue as well.

Answer (score 6):

Set `Application.ShutdownMode` to `ShutdownMode.OnExplicitShutdown`.

You can do this in your `App.xaml`, or anywhere else in C#.

```
<Application ... ShutdownMode="OnExplicitShutdown>
    ...
</Application>
```

Or in your `App.xaml.cs`:

```
ShutdownMode = ShutdownMode.OnExplicitShutdown;
```

Or somewhere else:

```
Application.Current.ShutdownMode = ShutdownMode.OnExplicitShutdown;
```

To shut down your application, you will need to call `Application.Shutdown()`:

```
Application.Current.Shutdown();
```

---

You can also set `Application.ShutdownMode` to `OnLastWindowClose`, to shut down your application when the last window is closed (rather than when the main window is closed). You can do this in any of the ways described above.

---

However, it sounds like the only reason you want to keep your main window alive is so that you can use it as a data store. I recommend using a separate object as your data store, and referencing it both from your InputWindow and your DisplayWindow.